# render listView to the next row when end of the screen width reached

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm using listView for my react-native application. Right now, `ListView` renders all items on the first row and I should scroll screen horizontally to see more after second item. However, I want to render only two item for each row. So how can I change my `ListView` so it renders only two items per row?

Here is my `ListView` implementation code.

```
<ListView contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', left: 5}}
                                     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                                     enableEmptySections={true}
                                     horizontal
                                     renderRow={(rowData)=>this.renderRow(rowData)}>
</ListView>
```

Here is how my `ListView` renders currently.

[image]

Comment: remove the `horizontal` attribute from the list view, and have `renderRow` return two items per row.

Comment: @NimrodArgov unfortunately, when I remove horizontal attribute, it renders 1 item per row.

Comment: Your `renderRow` function will have to return two elements per row, not just one.

Comment: @NimrodArgov thanks, man. You were right. I solved it.